# TypeScript: polymorphic return types in a base class?

Tags: typescript

I have a base class (Base) and two subclasses A and B.

Base has a method f that creates an instance of the current class and returns it. How do I ensure that when you call A.f(), it returns an instance of A instead of Base, and similarly for B? I don't want to have to define this method on A or B.

Here's some sample code:

```
class Base {
    name: string;

    constructor(name: string) { this.name = name; }

    f(): Base /* ? */ {
        return Base(name); /* or A(name) or B(name) depending on what "this" is

    }
}

class A extends Base { /* stuff */ }

class B extends Base { /* stuff */ }

var a = new A();
a.f() -> returns an instance of A, not Base
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take advantage of the `constructor` property:

```
class Base {
    name: string;

    constructor(name: string) { this.name = name; }

    f(name): Base {
        var c:any = this.constructor;
        return new c(name); /* or A(name) or B(name) depending on what "this" is */
    }
}

class A extends Base { /* stuff */ }

class B extends Base { /* stuff */ }

var a = new A("something");
var foo = a.f("foo") // -> returns an instance of A, not Base
console.log(foo.constructor);  // "A"

var b = new B("something else");
var bar = b.f("bar");
console.log(bar.constructor);  // "B"
```